# Show that every integer eigenvalue of $A$ divides the determinant of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ whose entries are all integers.
>   Show that every integer eigenvalue of $A$ divides the determinant of $A$.

I am not able to understand how to show this.
We know that $\det A$ is the product of eigen values and so every eigen value must divide $\det A$.

But if a matrix has eigen values $3$ and $\frac{4}{3}$ then if I do the product then the factor $3$  gets neutralized if I do the product then how does it appear as a factor of $\det A$?

Please help.

Comment: It says to show that every _integer_ eigenvalue divides the determinant. If there are other eigenvalues which are rational or real, don't worry about them.

Comment: @Joppy; what is there to prove then?

Comment: In your example where a $2 \times 2$ matrix has eigenvalues $3$ and $\frac{3}{4}$, the determinant will be $1$, and $4$ does not divide $1$. You need to show that this cannot happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$ be the charasteristic polynomial. Then $|P(0)|=|\det A|$. Moreover, the coefficients of $P$ are integer. If $\lambda$ is an integer eigenvalue, then 
$$0=P(\lambda)=P(0)+\sum_{k=1}^na_k\lambda^k$$
Therefore
$$|\det A|=|P(0)|=|\lambda|\cdot\left|\sum_{k=1}^na_k\lambda^{k-1}\right|$$
Hence $\lambda$ divides $\det A$.

Comment: So you mean that a matrix with integer entries always has eigen values as integers?

Comment: No, it can have irrational or complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @Find_X: But since the characteristic polynomial is [monic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial), the eigenvalues are algebraic integers and if they are rational, they are integer.

Comment: I don't understand one thing. $\det A$ is the product of eigen values so does it not follow trivially

Comment: @Find_X: it is also the constant coefficient of the characteristic polynomial, and that is what we are looking at here. That is, for any eigenvalue, $\lambda$, $$0=\det(A)+\sum_{k=1}^na_k\lambda^k$$ therefore $$\det(A)=-\lambda\sum_{k=1}^na_k\lambda^{k-1}$$

Comment: @robjohn; thank you very much